# Understanding Subject Public Key Info definition and indentation

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509, pki, asn.1

According to the IETF X.509 standard, the `Subject Public Key Info` is defined as:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

However, the (e.g.) google.com certificate contains the following for the `Subject Public Key Info`:

```
Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
      Public-Key: (256 bit)
      pub:
         04:e7:a5:a1:f8...
      ASN1 OID: prime256v1
      NIST CURVE: P-256
```

This confuses me for two reasons:

1. According to the definition, `subjectPublicKey` is supposed to be a bit string, but this seems to be a `SEQUENCE` in most certificates that I have looked at.
2. Why are the `pub`, `ANS1 OID` and `NIST CURVE` fields indented? My intuition is that these should be at the same level as `Public Key Algorithm`.

Comment: It *is* a BIT STRING, the tool you're using just does extra work to figure out what is inside the BIT STRING and displays that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second formatted output doesn't map 1:1 to ASN definition. It is the tool you are using to dump the certificate that decided to format the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` this way. You have to use ASN.1 viewer to view exact ASN.1. For example, in my ASN.1 Viewer, the google cert's public key looks like this:

[image]

`SubjectPublicKeyInfo` starts at offset 174, which is SEQUENCE. Next, at offset begins `AlgorithmIdentifier` structure which is SEQUENCE too. After `AlgorithmIdentifier` structure goes raw public key which is BIT_STRING as per ASN.1 module definition.